# How to convert values from a file to a Map in spark-scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have my values in a file as comma separated. Now, i want this data to be converted into a key value pairs(Maps). I know that we can split the values and store in a Array like below.

```
val prop_file = sc.textFile("/prop_file.txt") 
prop_file.map(_.split(",").map(s => Array(s)))
```

Is there any way to store the data as Map in spark-scala ?

Comment: How you will determine what is the key and what is the value for input like `a,b,c` ?

Comment: In my case, i have only 2 values separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each line of your file contain 2 values where first word is Key and next is value, separated by space: -

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

Something like this can be done: -

```
val file = sc.textFile("/prop_file.txt") 
val words = file.flatMap(x => createDataMap(x))
```

And here is your function - `createDataMap`

```
def createDataMap(data:String): Map[String, String] = {

 val array = data.split(",")
 //Creating the Map of values
 val dataMap = Map[String, String](
 (array(0) -> array(1)),
 (array(2) -> array(3))
)
return dataMap
}
```

Next for retrieving the key/ values from the RDD you can leverage following operations: -

```
//This will print all elements of RDD
words.foreach(f=>println(f))
//Or You can filter the elements too.
words.filter(f=>f._1.equals("A"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sumit. It worked. But now i have a problem while getting the values from the Map. When i try to do the below

val A = words.get("A")

It's giving me an error as "get is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Map[String,String]]"

can you please help me on this ?

Comment: Have added the operations for retrieving the values from RDD

Answer (score 0):

Sumit, I have used the below code to retrieve the value for a particular key and it worked.

```
val words = file.flatMap(x => createDataMap(x)).collectAsMap
val valueofA = props("A")
print(valueofA)
```

This gives me 1 as a result